# Doctrine2 / Move element from a Collection to another

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 3 entities : `Invoice`, `Service` and `Line`

- `Invoice` contains collection of `Service`
- `Service` contains collection of `Line`

I want to move one `Line` from a `Service` collection to another `Service` collection but on flush, the `Line` element that I try to move is deleted from the database ...

Unit tests are OK without persist / flush

Example of usage :

```
if ($transferService)
{
    $line->transferToService($service1, $service2);
}
else
{
    $line->setService($service2);
}
```

Invoice :

```
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="invoice", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $services;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    #################################################
    # SERVICES Array Collection handling            #
    #################################################

    public function getServices()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function setServices($services)
    {
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this->addServices($services);
    }

    public function addService(Service $service)
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service))
        {
            $this->services->add($service);
            $service->setInvoice($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addServices($services)
    {
        foreach ($services as $service)
        {
            $this->addService($service);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(Service $service)
    {
        if ($this->services->contains($service))
        {
            $this->services->removeElement($service);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeServices($services)
    {
        foreach ($services as $service)
        {
            $this->removeService($service);
        }

        return $this;
    }        

    // ...
}
```

Service :

```
class Service
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Line", mappedBy="service", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $lines;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice", inversedBy="services", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoice_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $invoice;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lines = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getInvoice()
    {
        return $this->invoice;
    }

    public function setInvoice(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
        $invoice->addService($this);

        return $this;
    }

    #################################################
    # LINES Array Collection handling               #
    #################################################

    public function setLines($lines)
    {
        $this->lines = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this->addLines($lines);
    }

    public function getLines()
    {
        return $this->lines;
    }

    public function addLine(Line $line)
    {
        if (!$this->lines->contains($line))
        {
            $this->lines->add($line);
            $line->setService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addLines($lines)
    {
        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            $this->addLine($line);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLine(Line $line)
    {
        if ($this->lines->contains($line))
        {
            $this->lines->removeElement($line);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLines($lines)
    {
        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            $this->removeLine($line);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Line :

```
class Line
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="lines", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $service;

    public function setService(Service $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
        $service->addLine($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function transferToService(Service $serviceFrom, Service $serviceTo)
    {
        $this->setService($serviceTo);
        $serviceFrom->removeLine($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to `orphanRemoval={true}`. That means that collection object is *privately* owned only from "original" owner (e.g.: `Line`).
[see here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)

Your code seems to work well unless - and maybe you didn't noticed - original elements are gone but they are also created again with different ids. Please check this situation as I've experienced the same more than once.

So, if you want to keep the same object, you should remove `orphanRemoval` and handle yourself, by hand, collection lifetime (including removing; I bet you're using this to write less code as possible in form collection and embedded forms)

Comment: Damn, you're completely right ! ( and you bet right too ;) "less code, less bug"). But original elements was not created again. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @ceadreak please pay attention: if your collection's primary keys are inserted with a foreign key constraint into other tables, this solution will not work anymore

Comment: @ DonCastillo what do you suggest then ?

Comment: @ceadreak if you have this kind of situation, remove orphanRemoval and handle element remove operation manually

Comment: Yep, that's what I did